# Is there any way of calculating inodes for a directory?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, inode

Could anybody tell me how to count number of inodes of files inside a directory ?

Thanks.

Comment: see here https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/linux/inode-count

Answer (score 0):

There is one [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) per directory, and one for each file in it.  If you symlink a file, the symlink gets it's own unique inode as well. (I'm sure someone will correctly me if I've missed any edge cases.)

List the inode number of each file:

`ls -i`

To count the number of files in the current directory:

`ls -1 | wc -l`

see also: [How to count number of files in multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216370/how-to-count-number-of-files-in-each-directory)