# Counting number of files in multiple subdirectories from command line

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I have a directory which contains a large number of subdirectories. Each subdirectory is named something like "treedir_xxx" where xxx is a number. I would like to run a command (preferably from the command line as I have no experience with batch scripts) that will count the number of files in each subdirectory named 'treedir_xxx' and write these numbers to a text file. I feel this should not be very difficult but so far I have been unsuccessful.

I have tried things like `find *treedir* -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l` however this just returns the total number of files rather than the number of files in each individual folder.

Comment: do subdirectories contain just files or also directories as well? That is, how deep is the tree of dirs?

Comment: this could help ;  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216370/how-to-count-number-of-files-in-each-directory

Comment: Or better yet: http://stackoverflow.com/q/307015/2988730

Comment: The subdirectories only contain files.

Comment: On a side note, all a shell script is (in it simplest form of course), is a list of the commands you ran on the command line, pasted into a text file and given execute permissions. Scripts are there to prevent you from having to type out the same dozen commands over and over, not to make your life harder (usually).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `find`, use a `for` loop. I am assuming that you are using `bash` or similar since that is the most common shell on most of the modern Linux distros:

```
for i in treedir_*; do ls "$i" | wc -l; done
```

Given the following structure:

```
treedir_001
 |__ a
 |__ b
 |__ c
treedir_002
 |__ d
 |__ e
treedir_003
 |__ f
```

The result is:

```
3
2
1
```

You can get fancy and print whatever you want around the numbers:

```
for i in treedir_*; do echo $i: $(ls "$i" | wc -l); done
```

gives

```
treedir_001: 3
treedir_002: 2
treedir_003: 1
```

This uses `$(...)` to get the output of a command as a string and pass it to `echo`, which can then print everything on one line.

```
for i in treedir_*; do echo $i; ls "$i" | wc -l; done
```

gives

```
treedir_001
3
treedir_002
2
treedir_003
1
```

This one illustrates the use of multiple commands in a single loop.

`for` can be redirected to a file or piped just like any other command, so you can do

```
for i in treedir_*; do ls "$i" | wc -l; done > list.txt
```

or better yet

```
for i in treedir_*; do ls "$i" | wc -l; done | tee list.txt
```

The second version sends the output to the program `tee`, which prints it to standard output and also redirects it to a file. This is sometimes nicer for debugging than a simple redirect with `>`.

`find` is a powerful hammer, but not everything is a nail...

Comment: Excellent thank you, I included a '>fnum.txt' to write it to a text file, but this works brilliantly.