# recursively list number of entries in each directory

Tags: bash

I have a directory which contains sub-directories, which in turn contain sub-directories, which contain files. How can I list the number of files in each sub-directory recursively?

from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216370/how-to-count-number-of-files-in-each-directory?noredirect=1&lq=1) I know that

```
du -a | cut -d/ -f2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

will list the number of files on the current directory level. How can I do this recursively?

I have also seen [this possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850834/counting-number-of-files-in-multiple-subdirectories-from-command-line?noredirect=1&lq=1), however I can't get it to work for my specific problem.

Comment: `man find` is a good start.

Comment: `find -type f`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I guess you misunderstood the question; OP wants to count files in each directory in the hierarchy and list them **separately**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conjunction of find and sh could easily do the trick. E.g.:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
for d; do
  set -- "$d/"*
  printf "%d\t%s\n" $# "$d"
done' _ {} +
```