# How to delete a subfolder with only a single file under the parent folder

Tags: linux, unix

I have a folder with 8000 subfolders, and want to delete those subfolders that only contain one file

Comment: Hi! Please add some samples about `folder`, `subfolders` for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering all of the `subfolders` are in the same folder with no "sub-sub" depth, `find` command prints subfolders with this one-liner and `bash` handles the rest:

Sample folder and files:

```
$ find . 
.
./subfolder_1
./subfolder_1/file1
./subfolder_1/file2
./subfolder_1/file3
./subfolder_2
./subfolder_2/file4
./subfolder_3
./subfolder_3/file5
./subfolder_3/file6
./subfolder_4
./subfolder_5
./subfolder_5/file7
```

**One liner to remove subfolders containing only one file:**

```
$ find . -not -empty -type d -print0 | while read -d '' -r dir; do files=("$dir"/*); if((${#files[@]} == "1")); then rm -r $dir exit; fi; done
```

List of what is remained after removing

```
$ find . 
.
./subfolder_1
./subfolder_1/file1
./subfolder_1/file2
./subfolder_1/file3
./subfolder_3
./subfolder_3/file5
./subfolder_3/file6
./subfolder_4
```

---

### Extra

**List of subfolders with the number of files included:**

```
$ find . -not -empty -type d -print0 | while read -d '' -r dir; do files=("$dir"/*); printf "${#files[@]}  $dir\n"; done
    6  .
    3  ./subfolder_1
    1  ./subfolder_2
    2  ./subfolder_3
    1  ./subfolder_5
```

**List of subfolders containing only one file:**

```
$ find . -not -empty -type d -print0 | while read -d '' -r dir; do files=("$dir"/*); if((${#files[@]} == "1")); then printf "${#files[@]}  $dir\n" exit; fi; done
1  ./subfolder_2
1  ./subfolder_5
```

Comment: Thank you very much! ! ! This is exactly what I want as a newbie to bash shell script

Comment: I am glad you benefit it. This is a modification from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15221702/14320738 you can examine this post for more information.